# MK5 doesn't switch on

Tags: electrical, vw, golf, dashboard

I have a 2004 golf5 fsi 2.0 model. The car suddenly cannot switch on,if i try to lock the doors manually, only the drivers door locks. Central lock not working apparently. It started well this morning and i drove to work about 6km from my home and after i parked and tried to lock using immobilizer nothing happened. Key turns well in ignition but the car won't switch on nor start plus there areno lights on the dashboard, battery is ok. Please help..

Comment: How have you established that the battery is ok?

Comment: It's a new one, fitted last month.

Comment: The symptoms you describe would be exactly what I'd expect to see from a dead battery.  I'd check the fuse cover ontop of the battery first plus the security of the battery terminal clamps.

Comment: Thanks so much Steve Matthews..I removed battery terminals and tightened them back again.You were right I suspect a loose terminal.

Comment: >>    It's a new one, fitted last month . . . ALWAYS suspect the last thing touched.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you describe would be exactly what I'd expect to see from a dead battery. I'd check the fuse cover ontop of the battery first plus the security of the battery terminal clamps.